resize height of image when shrinking viewport height
I've search everywhere but I can't find a solution to keep image in viewport when shrinking vertical height of window. Here's a screenshot that shows what I'm try to do. Any consideration appreciated!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Slideshow</title>
<style>
  body::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
  body {margin:0;}

  /* .container img {
    height: 100%;
  } */

  img {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <img src="wallpaper.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
 


You should use height: 100vh;. It's the View Height of the window.

Using height: 100dvh; makes the image dynamically adjust to the viewport's size, ensuring it fits the screen even with dynamic changes like expanding user interfaces.
